# Confusion about how to update kubernetes jobs

Tags: kubernetes, job-scheduling

I am eagerly awaiting the release of Kubernetes v1.3 in mid to late June, so that I can access cron scheduling for jobs. In the meantime, what I plan to do is the following:

- Deploy a job on my Kubernetes cluster
- Use jenkins as a cron tool to trigger the job in defined intervals (e.g. 1 hour).

I have two questions:

How do I update a job? For replication controllers, I would simply do a rolling update, but in the jobs API spec (http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jobs/) there are no details about how to do this. For example, lets say that I want to use my jenkins deploy system to update the job whenever I do a git commit.

Is it possible to use the kubernetes API to trigger jobs? For example, I have a job that runs and then the pod is terminated on completion. Then, 1 hour later, I want to use jenkins to trigger the job again.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Sadly Scheduled Jobs (Cron) [have been late for 1.3 and are coming in 1.4 only](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/11980)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any fancy way to trigger a completed job, but one way to do it can be to delete and recreate the job.

Re: rolling-update: that is required for long running pods, which is what RCs control.
For jobs: You can update the podTemplateSpec in jobSpec and that will ensure that any new pod created  by the job after the update will have the updated podTemplateSpec (note: already running pods will not be affected).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I ended up using a kubernetes daemon set for cron, having the docker entrypoint start the cron and tail the log

Comment: > podTemplateSpec in jobSpec

: This doesn't work,  podTemplateSpec is immutable. So you cant edit the job by updating any fields in podTemplateSpec